# Macbook pro crashes Whenever installing Matlab 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, crash, matlab

Okay so, I have a *Macbook Pro mid-2012 macOS Sierra 8GB of RAM, 256GB SSD*. I need Matlab for my work. And whenever I put Matlab on installation it does install up to ***60%*** but in it sixties somewhere the Mac crashes. Showing me a gray background saying "You are seeing this screen because of a problem with your mac...". I cannot understand where is the problem.

There is another problem. That is, my mac wont will work properly if I used it as long as I want then turn it off and wait for an hour or so to start it again. If I start it up right-away it would show a prohibition symbol on bootup and in verbose mode would say ***"Read Error--Kernel Cache Read error"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never mentioned which version of MATLAB you were running.  However, the 9.0 ([R2016a](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2016a_Macintosh.pdf)) doesn't mention Sierra at all and the [R2016b](https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq.html) which does list Sierra support has it as "limited."

First thing I would do is verify that your version of MATLAB is compatible with Sierra.

Secondly, a read error is indicative of a drive error.  It could be a corruption of the file or it could be a physical error.  You need to at least run First Aid on your drive to see if there are any problems.

Comment: Yes thanks, i did run first aid on the only drive that i have and it says, **problems were found with partition map that might prevent booting**.. Can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: That would be a new question because on this site, it's one topic per question.  However, a [quick search](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=problems+found+partition+prevent+booting)  lists a number of similar problems and solutions.  If one of those questions/answers don't solve your issue, go ahead and open up a new question.